# Counting points within range using CartoDB?

Tags: postgis, carto, sql, distance, count

I have a dataset of users location and want to assign per user how many other users they have within a given range, and updating this value into a table.The dataset name is "users_20160410" and the column to be updated is "countdistance"

I have manage to get the number of total users within 10km for a given point, which is a unique value:

```
UPDATE users_20160410 SET countdistance = (select count(*) from users_20160410 where st_distance(the_geom,st_GeomFromText('POINT(-3.703550 40.417192)', 4326), true) < 10000)
```

What I want is to know for every single user how many other user he has within a range of 10km (this means get a value per user, not 1 unique as per my previous query). Also as the distance is not a fixed given point, the st_Geom_From_Text could not be used as it should take the exact location per user.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to update from the results of another query. For performance it's best to do within the context of an indexed column, so you end up with some ugliness.

```
WITH sums AS (
  SELECT a.cartodb_id AS cartodb_id, Count(*) as count, sum(a.popn) as popn
  FROM populated_places_esp a
  JOIN populated_places_esp b 
    ON ST_DWithin(
      a.the_geom_webmercator, 
      b.the_geom_webmercator, 
      10000 / cos(radians(st_y(a.the_geom))))
  GROUP BY a.cartodb_id
)
UPDATE populated_places_esp 
  SET countdistance = sums.count
  FROM sums
  WHERE sums.cartodb_id = populated_places_esp.cartodb_id;
```

The normalization of the distance by `cos(latitude)` is to make up for distortions from the mercator projection.

Comment: Query from @ramiroaznar works perfect thought is not updating the table. Paul, your query is giving me an error "column cartodb_id" is ambiguous. Here the used query:
WITH sums AS (
  SELECT a.cartodb_id AS cartodb_id, Count(*) as count, sum(a.id) as id
  FROM users_20160410 a
  JOIN users_20160410 b 
    ON ST_DWithin(
      a.the_geom_webmercator, 
      b.the_geom_webmercator, 
      10000 / cos(radians(st_y(a.the_geom))))
  GROUP BY a.cartodb_id
)
UPDATE users_20160410 
  SET countdistance = sums.count
  FROM sums
  WHERE sums.cartodb_id = cartodb_id

Answer (score 0):

Using Spanish cities from `populated_places` as an example table, the following SQL query count the number of closest (100 Km) neighbors of each city:

```
SELECT  
p.name, COUNT(*) AS num_neigh 
FROM
populated_places_esp n,
populated_places_esp p 
WHERE
ST_DWithin(p.the_geom::geography, n.the_geom::geography, 100000) 
AND
p.cartodb_id != n.cartodb_id 
GROUP BY p.name 
ORDER BY num_neigh DESC
```